# Kак активировать Aякс при нажатие Enter в поле input

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Надо отправлять Aяксом инфу из поля `<input>` на сервер (при этом, при нажатии на <kbd>Enter</kbd>, должна отправляться эта инфа) *без использования `<form>`*.

Comment: Чем вам form не угодил? К form тоже можно прикрутить аякс

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```js
var element = document.querySelector("input");
element.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  var key = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if (key == 13) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("input", this.value)
    request.open("POST", "url");
    request.send(formData);
  }
});
```

```html
<input>
```

Answer (score 1):

В общем выглядеть это должно как-то так. 
url, headers, method , и все остальные параметры смотри в доккументациик методу fetch. некоторые из этих параметров у тебя будут  другие. может не самое красивое решени..но.. что нашел, то прислал)))

```js
function ajax(url,data,callback){
        var formData = new FormData();
        let heder = new Headers({ 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' });
        formData.append('action', JSON.stringify(data));
        fetch(url, {
            method: 'post',
            headers: heder,
            credentials: "same-origin",
            body: formData,
        }).then(validateResponse).then(function(result) {
            if(typeof callback === 'function') {
                    return callback(result.result);
            }
        });
      function validateResponse(response) {
        if(!response.ok) {
            throw Error(response.statusText);
        }
        return response.json();
    }
}

let input =  document.getElementById('text');
input.addEventListener('keydown',(event)=>{
  if(event.keyCode===13){
    ajax('http://example.com',event.target.value,()=>{});
  }
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Какой вопрос - такой ответ**

Добавить к инпуту прослушивание события и используя фетч или xhr отправлять ©"ину из поля на сервер".